¿Cómo retorno un string de una función en C?
Quiero hacer una función en C que tome dos strings como parámetros y que los concatene, y que al ejecutar la función el string lo pueda guardar en una variable y luego imprimirlo, pero al ejecutar el programa me devuelve null. El código es el siguiente. Gracias!
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* concatenate(char* s1, char* s2) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *a;

    while (s1[i] != 0) {
        a[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }

    while (s2[j] != 0) {
        a[i] = s2[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    return a;
 }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* s1 = "Ramon";
    char* s2 = "Ricardo";

    printf("Concateno \"%s\" con \"%s\":",s1, s2);

    char* concat = concatenate(s1, s2);

    printf(" \"%s\"\n",concat);

    free(concat);

    return 0;
}


Pst:: No puedo usar otras librerías como malloc (es para una materia de la universidad).

Lo primero que noto es que usas  free(concat); que no es necesario, además como comentas no debes usar la función malloc()

Agregue una respuesta Ariana, te sugiero pruebes el código, aunque veo alguién me puntuo negativamente sin hacer comentario. @ArianaBlanco

El problema con tu código es que no estás asignando memoria para la cadena concatenada.
En C, cuando declaras un puntero, no se asigna automáticamente memoria para los datos a los que se supone que apunta. Necesitas usar una función como malloc para asignar memoria.
Ahora, si dices que no puedes usar malloc entonces podrías usar una matriz de tamaño fijo para almacenar la cadena concatenada. Sin embargo, este método tiene sus propias limitaciones, ya que es necesario conocer de antemano el tamaño máximo de la cadena concatenada.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_LENGTH 100 // Definir la longitud máxima de la cadena concatenada

char* concatenate(char* s1, char* s2) {
 static char a[MAX_LENGTH]; // Utiliza una matriz estática para almacenar la cadena concatenada 

Lo siguiente sería comprobar si la cadena concatenada cabe en la matriz y es aquí en donde usas un if para saber si la cadena es larga
 if (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + 1 > MAX_LENGTH) {
    printf("La cadena concatenada es muy larga\n");
    return NULL;
}

Después copias la primera cadena a la matriz, la concatenas a la segunda cadena y haces un return en a
strcpy(a, s1);

strcat(a, s2);

return a;
}

Recuerda eliminar el free(concat) porque ya no lo estarías utilizando

Debes modificar tu función concatenate(), te sugiero simplemente usar un array donde almacenes el resultado de la la concatenación
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*char* concatenate(char* s1, char* s2) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *a;

    while (s1[i] != 0) {
        a[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }

    while (s2[j] != 0) {
        a[i] = s2[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    return a;
 }*/
 
 char* concatenate(char* s1, char* s2) {

    char* resultado; //*Almacena resultado de concatenacion.
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (s1[i] != '\0') {
        resultado[i] = s1[i]; //* Copia s1 a resultado
        i++;
    }

    while (s2[j] != '\0') {
        resultado[i] = s2[j];  //* Compia s2 a resultado
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    resultado[i] = '\0'; //*Agregar para definir terminación de resultado.
    return resultado;
}
 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char* s1 = "Ramon";
    char* s2 = "Ricardo";

    printf("Concateno \"%s\" con \"%s\":",s1, s2);

    char* concat = concatenate(s1, s2);
    
    printf("\nconcat: \"%s\"\n",concat);

    //free(concat);

    return 0;
}

De esta forma tendrías como salida:
Concateno "Ramon" con "Ricardo":
concat: "RamonRicardo"


Gracias! Lo pude solucionar.

Recuerda que si mi respuesta ayudó a resolver el problema de la pregunta, puedes marcar como solución, revisa [tour]


¿A dónde apunta el puntero a? A una dirección de memoria desconocida. Está mal usar un puntero sin inicializar. Tienes que darle algún valor como: cero (null), la dirección de una variable conocida o una dirección generada por alguna función como malloc.

En C es típico trabajar con cadenas terminadas en un caracter nulo (o lo que es lo mismo, 0). Tu función no termina las nuevas cadenas correctamente.

No reservaste memoria sin embargo estás intentando liberarla. Solo usa free con punteros obtenidos con malloc.



Finalizar la cadena correctamente es fácil, solo agrega la siguiente línea antes del return:
a[i] = 0; 

Para inicializar el puntero, cero no es va a ser útil ya que quieres guardar información y el cero tiene un significado especial: el puntero no apunta a ninguna parte (o lo que se conoce como null en otros lenguajes).
Si no puedes reservar memoria con malloc, otra opción es usar un arreglo.
char a[100];

char* concatenate(char* s1, char* s2) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while (s1[i] != 0) {
        a[i] = s1[i];
        i++;
    }

    while (s2[j] != 0) {
        a[i] = s2[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    // Finalizamos la cadena
    a[i] = 0; 
    return a;
}

Otra posibilidad es que el arreglo venga como parámetro:
char* concatenate(char* a, char* s1, char* s2) {
    ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buffer[100];
    char* s1 = "Ramon";
    char* s2 = "Ricardo";

    printf("Concateno \"%s\" con \"%s\":",s1, s2);

    char* concat = concatenate(buffer, s1, s2);

    printf(" \"%s\"\n",concat);

    return 0;
}


Gracias! Ya lo pude solucionar.
